# How to cite an article from a magazine (no date, published quarterly) in MLA7?

Tags: citations

I’m writing a comparative research analysis for my freshman writing requirement class on the school-to-prison pipeline, and I’m trying to cite [this article by John DiIulio](http://www.city-journal.org/html/6_2_my_black.html). The site doesn’t give a date of publication, and I can’t find any dates online for the print publication date; all I know is that it was the spring edition of 1996.

How do I cite this in the [MLA7 style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_MLA_Style_Manual)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant citation is provided in the [site itself](http://www.unz.org/Pub/CityJournal-1996q1-00014).

```
 My Black Crime Problem, and Ours by John J. DiIulio, Jr. 
 City Journal, Spring 1996, pp. 14-28
```

To cite in MLA7:

> DiIulio, John J., Jr. “My Black Crime Problem, and Ours.” *City Journal*, Spring 1996: 14-28. Print.

Hope this answers your quesion.